# SonarQube 6.2 installation issue

Tags: sonarqube

I am facing the following issue while running startSonar.bat:

> --> Wrapper Started as Console
>   Launching a JVM...
>   Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
>     Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>
> WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
>     java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]
>
> Where:
>     app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
>     app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
>                     application.
>   <-- Wrapper Stopped

I am trying to run SonarQube on 64 bit Windows Server R2. It is an old server from 2009.

I tried few things like appending the Java and SonarQube paths in PATH environment variable. Besides this I tried to provide an absolute path for `wrapper.java.command` in wrapper.conf.

Answer (score 4):

According to the error message ("Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"), you are using an old JDK. To fix this, you have to install the JDK 8 and configure wrapper.java.command to point to the installation of this JDK 8.